# Jquery Selector :not inside child div

Tags: jquery, css

I want to be able to use jquery to bind a click event on the `body` tag but not inside a child div with class='noclick'.

```
<div>
    <div>you can click here</div>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class='noclick'>NO ALERT</div>
</div>
```

This doesn't work

```
$("body:not(.noclick)").on('click', function (e) {
    alert("clicked")
});
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zmzwhvy/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, the [`:not()` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) isn't doing anything.

The jQuery selector `$("body:not(.noclick)")` will select a `body` element that does not have the class `.noclick`. In your example, the `body` element doesn't have a class of `.noclick`, which means that it will be selected and the click event will bubble up to the `body` element regardless and the function will be fired.

You can access a reference to the clicked element by retrieving the [`target` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) of the `event` object (which is `e.target` in this example).

From there, you can use the [`.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to determine if the clicked element has an ancestor with class `.noclick` *or* if the current element has a class of `.noclick`.

> [**`.closest()` method:**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
>
> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/g7mvud0s/)

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest('.noclick').length) {
        alert('Alert');
    }
});
```

Comment: Sweet! This is pretty clean.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is actually working, except that clicks bubble up the DOM, so you need to catch the click on the .noclick element and stop it from propagating. One way to do that:

```
$('.noclick').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on('click', function (e) {
  if(!$(e.target).hasClass('noclick')){
    alert("clicked");
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the div more properly. You have .noclick div inside another div, and so that div's click is fired. If you specify div > div:not(.noclick) , it will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("div>div:not(.noclick)").on('click', function (e) {
      alert("clicked")
    });
});
```